# Highlight fields of structures in the Matlab internal editor?

Tags: matlab, structure, highlight

When you select a structure in the Matlab Editor, it highlights the name of the structure all over your script.
[Image: Matlab highlighting of structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69d8q.png)

Is there a way, to also get this highlighting for when you select a field (child) of a structure?

If not: Is there a good alternative to the Matlab-internal editor, which highlights the structure fields and supports code-completion (for variable names, integrated Matlab functions,...)?

Comment: Not possible in MATLAB, that I know of. You could have some luck with an editor like [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/), which has (customizable) MATLAB syntax. Potentially not a trivial question either, is there going to be a distinction between structure fields and class methods?